# How to replace some rows in a SELECT query from another SELECT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have two tables:

T1:

```
ID    Department   ATTRIBUTES  TEAM  
---   ----------   ----------  ------
1     R&D          Dress_Code  NULL
2     R&D          Dress_Code  Web
3     R&D          Food        System
4     R&D          Food        NULL
5     R&D          Color       NULL
6     Marketing    Food        System
```

T2:

```
ID    VAL  
---   ----------
1     Smart
2     Casual
3     Beef
4     Chicken
5     Green
6     Fish
```

The purpose of T1 is to show all the department attributes.

If the TEAM is null, it is for everyone in that department. Sometimes a team has special settings which override the generic settings.

For example, I want to get the settings as a 'Web' team in R&D.

I can write:

```
SELECT T1.DEPARTMENT, T1.ATTRIBUTES, T1.TEAM, T2.VAL 
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
WHERE T1.DEPARTMENT = 'R&D' AND T1.TEAM = 'Web'
```

This will show one record which says dress code is casual.

But I want the result to be:

```
ATTRIBUTES  VAL  
----------  ------
Dress_Code  Casual
Food        Chicken
Color       Green
```

Similarly for the 'System' team in R&D, the result would be smart dress code, beef, and green color.

I'm thinking first select all R&D results and then replace the rows with the above select results.

I need to write this as a stored procedure.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Can you write down the logic of matching? Based on the two tables that you wrote, I cannot see why "Food-Attributes" has to match with "Chicken-Val" and not with "Casual-Val" or "Green-Val".

Comment: specify Maxrecusrion in your CTE as well this will help to recursive the self loop. The max is 32767 default is 0 and if don'd know at how much level u will have to to recursion specify 0.

Comment: @DVT The problem I was trying to solve involves other rows and columns as well. I simplified it into T1 and T2 as shown (although it looks like I can simply put them into a single table, I can't do that with my original tables). So in this case, I match by T1.ID = T2.ID.

Answer (score 1):

Using CTE and row_number() :

```
with CTE as(
    select  
        ATTRIBUTES,
        VAL,                
        T1.TEAM,
        row_number() over (partition by ATTRIBUTES order by team desc) rn 
    from t1 t1 
    inner join t2 t2 on t1.ID =t2.ID   
    AND (  T1.TEAM = 'Web' or T1.TEAM is  null )
)
select 
    ATTRIBUTES  , 
    VAL 
from cte where rn=1
order by val
```

> OutPut :

[image]

Comment: Works but a bit too smart. I need some time to digest :) +1

Comment: @Zelurd Google it . execute one by one line which easy to understand working.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    T1.DEPARTMENT, 
    T1.ATTRIBUTES, 
    T1.TEAM, 
    T2.VAL 
INTO #temp
FROM T1
INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
WHERE T1.TEAM is NULL

SELECT 
    T1.ATTRIBUTES,
    T2.VAL 
INTO #t2
FROM T1
INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
WHERE T1.TEAM = 'Web'

UPDATE t 
SET t.VAL=b.VAL
FROM #temp t
join #t2 b on b.ATTRIBUTES=t.ATTRIBUTES

SELECT 
    DEPARTMENT,     
    ATTRIBUTES, 
    TEAM, 
    VAL
FROM #temp
```

Even this too will help.